# Updating variable name within a for loop while performing calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Whenever I stumble across some sort of calculation in Python, I tend to do go for an unpythonic approach because I am not too familiar with the language:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

v        = 8
gf       = 2.5

data_a1  = np.random.randint(5, 10, 21)
data_a2  = np.random.randint(5, 10, 21)
data_a3  = np.random.randint(5, 10, 21)
data_a4  = np.random.randint(5, 10, 21)
data_a5  = np.random.randint(5, 10, 21)

data_b1  = np.random.randint(6, 11, 21)
data_b2  = np.random.randint(6, 11, 21)
data_b3  = np.random.randint(6, 11, 21)
data_b4  = np.random.randint(6, 11, 21)
data_b5  = np.random.randint(6, 11, 21)

e_1 = 2 * (data_a1 + data_b1) / 2 / v / gf
e_2 = 2 * (data_a2 + data_b2) / 2 / v / gf
e_3 = 2 * (data_a3 + data_b3) / 2 / v / gf
e_4 = 2 * (data_a4 + data_b4) / 2 / v / gf
e_5 = 2 * (data_a5 + data_b5) / 2 / v / gf
```

As you can see from the example above, I explicitly write it down five times instead of using Python how I can imagine it is intended to be used -- I would like to calculate `e` by updating it on every iteration using a for loop, and I would also prefer to use `numpy`.

Since all my effort was not bearing fruits, I turned to `pandas` because I was fairly confident that I could redeem myself for whatever reason:

```
df_a     = pd.DataFrame({'data_a1': data_a1, 'data_a2': data_a2, 'data_a3': data_a3, 'data_a4': data_a4, 'data_a5': data_a5})
df_b     = pd.DataFrame({'data_b1': data_b1, 'data_b2': data_b2, 'data_b3': data_b3, 'data_b4': data_b4, 'data_b5': data_b5})

c   = 0
dfs = []
for i,j in zip(df_a, df_b):
    e = 2 * (i + j) / 2 / v / gf
    e = e.add_suffix('_' + str(c))
    dfs.addpend(e)
    c += 1
```

Alas, my stupidity prevailed itself and I could not do it either way.

- Is there a streamlined way to work with equations using `numpy` so that the variable is updating itself within a for loop that is considered pythonic?
- When performing these tasks, is it recommended to stick to `numpy` or turn to `pandas`?

Answer (score 3):

First let's step away from creating a lot of variable names.  In Python lists can contain other objects including arrays.

```
datalist1 = []
for _ in range(5):
    datalist1.append(np.random.randin(5, 10, 21))
# same for datalist2
datalist2 = [np.random.randint(6, 11, 21), 
             np.random.randint(6, 11, 21),
            ...]

elist = [2*(a+b)/2/v/gf for a,b in zip(datalist1, datalist2)]
```

Working 2d arrays, with shape (5,21) is even better.  But the kind of list iteration that I illustrate works for all of Python, not just `numpy`.

You could even make a list from pre existing variables:

```
alist = [data_b1, data_b2, ...]
```

Comment: Thank toy for replying, hpaulj. I am sorry if my question is misleading. The random arrays were created as an example but, in reality, I work with lab data acquired at different times. That is why I wanted to distinguish between the variables by adding a suffix of some sort. Would you advise me to store all the data in an array and then perform the calculations on the lists themselves?

Comment: You can still use lists, or dictionaries.  For example you could have a list of the 'times'.  But if in effect you have one or more time series, then `pandas` may be the way to go.  The focus of my answer was on replacing a whole bunch of variable names with lists.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding your intent, but from what I can tell, you aren't inexing or looking up anything, so there's no reason to go from numpy into pandas (which is just a really really well-dressed numpy array). Instead, you should be looking at the vectorized operations numpy provides.

Again, I'm not clear on your end goal, since you didn;t provide output, but is this approaching what you're after?

```
v        = 8
gf       = 2.5
a=np.random.randint(5,10,(21,5))
b=np.random.randint(5,10,(21,5))
c=2*(a+b)/2/v/gf

c

array([[0.9 , 0.75, 0.75, 0.6 , 0.65],
       [0.75, 0.65, 0.5 , 0.9 , 0.75],
       [0.7 , 0.6 , 0.75, 0.75, 0.85],
       [0.6 , 0.6 , 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.7 ],
       [0.6 , 0.75, 0.9 , 0.8 , 0.8 ],
       [0.85, 0.65, 0.65, 0.7 , 0.65],
       [0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.55, 0.7 ],
       [0.5 , 0.7 , 0.7 , 0.55, 0.6 ],
       [0.65, 0.6 , 0.8 , 0.9 , 0.7 ],
       [0.65, 0.7 , 0.55, 0.6 , 0.8 ],
       [0.75, 0.55, 0.75, 0.7 , 0.65],
       [0.8 , 0.7 , 0.65, 0.7 , 0.55],
       [0.55, 0.8 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.7 ],
       [0.8 , 0.75, 0.7 , 0.85, 0.7 ],
       [0.7 , 0.55, 0.75, 0.7 , 0.55],
       [0.6 , 0.7 , 0.7 , 0.6 , 0.65],
       [0.55, 0.8 , 0.7 , 0.6 , 0.75],
       [0.65, 0.75, 0.7 , 0.65, 0.6 ],
       [0.8 , 0.85, 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.7 ],
       [0.85, 0.8 , 0.55, 0.6 , 0.8 ],
       [0.8 , 0.8 , 0.75, 0.7 , 0.7 ]])
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, G. Anderson. I created the random variables as an example, whereas in real life I am working with data acquired in a laboratory setting. Since I am performing the same measurement at different times, I wanted to distinguish between the arrays and update them with, for example, a suffix of some sort. I apologize for the poor explanation.

Comment: See my additional answer, maybe closer to your intent?

Answer (score 1):

So, given additional information, what about this:

```
#simulate getting new data every day for a week
n_days   = 7

#set constants
v        = 8
gf       = 2.5
data_dict={}
#append data
for i in range(n_days+1):
    a=np.random.randint(5,10,21)
    b=np.random.randint(5,10,21)
    data_dict['dayN+'+str(i)]=2*(a+b)/2/v/gf #instead of str(i), you could append the key with datetime.now(), etc.

data_dict

{'dayN+0': array([0.275, 0.275, 0.4  , 0.3  , 0.325, 0.425, 0.4  , 0.45 , 0.3  ,
        0.375, 0.375, 0.35 , 0.425, 0.35 , 0.4  , 0.325, 0.3  , 0.3  ,
        0.35 , 0.3  , 0.375]),
 'dayN+1': array([0.3  , 0.275, 0.325, 0.375, 0.4  , 0.425, 0.325, 0.325, 0.4  ,
        0.35 , 0.3  , 0.4  , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.375, 0.45 , 0.35 ,
        0.425, 0.35 , 0.4  ]),
 'dayN+2': array([0.4...
```